# How to create android drawable consisting of two colors side by side?

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, xml-drawable

Uisng XML is it possible to create a drawable where half of it would be color1 and another half would be color2? When I set that drawable as a background of a view it should look like in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Doing it by xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:right="100dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:height="100dp" android:width="100dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:left="100dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:height="100dp" android:width="100dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Put it in `res/drawable` folder and assign as `android:background` to image

Comment: Thanks. This solution is closest to what I want to achieve.

Comment: if u set this drawable as background inside of a layout it will be static (200dp height)

Answer (score 4):

### By xml:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="90">
<shape>
    <gradient
        android:centerX="-10.0"
        android:endColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:startColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:type="sweep" />
</shape>
```

Fit to any view size.

### You can also use the 9-Patch file:

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch

Comment: Don't forget add </rotate> at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by creating 2 shapes with respective colors and then use them.

You can make these shapes by writing xml for them giving the dimensions and colors.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can :

1) Create a shape

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:shape="rectangle" >

  <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/gray_light" />

  <gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:centerX="0"
    android:centerY="1"
    android:startColor="#bff54a"
    android:endColor="#88c010" />

  <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

2) Extends the drawable class

```
public class ColorBarDrawable extends Drawable {

    private int[] themeColors;

    public ColorBarDrawable(int[] themeColors) {
        this.themeColors = themeColors;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        // get drawable dimensions
        Rect bounds = getBounds();

        int width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
        int height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;

        // draw background gradient
        Paint backgroundPaint = new Paint();
        int barWidth = width / themeColors.length;
        int barWidthRemainder = width % themeColors.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < themeColors.length; i++) {
            backgroundPaint.setColor(themeColors[i]);
            canvas.drawRect(i * barWidth, 0, (i + 1) * barWidth, height, backgroundPaint);
        }

        // draw remainder, if exists
        if (barWidthRemainder > 0) {
            canvas.drawRect(themeColors.length * barWidth, 0, themeColors.length * barWidth + barWidthRemainder, height, backgroundPaint);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
    }

}
```

*Source : Chiral Code - StackOverflow*