# Drawing 2 rectangle with cut inbetween

Tags: android, xml

i want to draw in xml with given exmaple [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf2ir.png)

i tried with [this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126248/how-to-create-android-drawable-consisting-of-two-colors-side-by-side)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"><item android:right="100dp">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="100dp" android:width="100dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</shape></item><item android:left="100dp"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="100dp" android:width="100dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
</shape></item></layer-list>
```

but it doesnt have middle cut between 2 shapes.also given shape should work with any width .so dont want do define any width restrictions

[result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn7yA.png)

Comment: is it for button style?

Comment: @droid edited my code checked it now

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

use this **style**

```
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFCD80"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="45" android:toDegrees="0" android:pivotX="20%" android:pivotY="10%" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

**layout**

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:context=".game.GameActionActivity" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style_twocolor_center_crossline" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: nope it not giving same result .bottom left showing gold color

Comment: red color shape is not taking full width . 1st half of the shape should cover at least 45% of the width

Comment: I don't know for which component your are going to use this style. I used it for button with static height & width. see my updated answer.

Comment: both are wrap content its on relativeLayout

Comment: still it giving 3 types of section 1 with small gold 2 is red and 3 is again gold

Comment: check result1 image for ref its coming like this edit my qus

Comment: <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0):

change color as you what.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">

<path
    android:fillColor="#fff8bb"
    android:pathData="M0,0
                  L0,24
                  L24,24
                  L24,0 z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#ffc5bb"
    android:pathData="M0,14
                  L8,24
                  L22,24
                  L8,0
                  L0,0z" />
</vector>
```

In xml file

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cust_rect"/>
```

[image: output will be]